# In wordpress, where does function_exists(), look to decide whether a function exists?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

**Background:** My original question was posted [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/125443/41479) on [Wordpress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)
but it may be more appropriate for this audience due to its relevancy to PHP.

**Question:** When using `function_exists()` in Wordpress theme development, where does that function look to decide whether a function exists?

For example if I have `if ( function_exists( 'get_custom_header' )` in header.php, where will the function look for get_custom_header?

**Special Note:** From what I understand, the function refers to hash table that is made up of all the functions found by the parser so far, including any `includes` see [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/125456/41479)
post.

Comment: It will look at your `complete` source code of course, which includes all the included files. And oh those PHP default functions as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the PHP lookup tables for all loaded files. Basically, if you open and parse a file, PHP itself knows what's in it, and that's what the function uses to check a function exists.

Obviously this applies to native functions also.

Edit: Yes, your linked post is 100% correct. What do you want with this information though?

Comment: Thanks. If you look in my comment here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/125447/41479 , I am still confused as to how `if (function_exists('get_custom_header'))` can work. I know the code is correctly checking and finding the `get_custom_header`, but I know it lives in functions.php, and I don't know how the php parser could have looked in functions.php, because I did not include it, nor is it in header.php.

Comment: Wordpress does a whole bunch of bootstrapping and autoloading. I presume that somewhere during the theme bootstrap does it load your functions.php file

Comment: Line 286 in wp-settings.php is the code block that loads in the files.

Comment: do you mean `do_action( 'setup_theme' );` ? I just want to make sure just in case there is a difference due to Wordpress versions. Also, thank you very much for your help. May I ask how you were able to figure this out?

Comment: I presume in setup_theme, yes, but I'm not 100% sure. I did a project-wide search for the `include` that included functions.php